# add AdMob in Xcode

Tags: swift, admob

I want to add AdMob in Xcode but not add and I see problem Thread 1: signal SIGABRT

```
import UIKit
import GoogleMobileAds

class ViewController: UIViewController, GADBannerViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var banner: GADBannerView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        banner.isHidden = true
        banner.delegate = self
        banner.adUnitID = "my id"
        banner.adSize = kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait
        banner.rootViewController = self
        banner.load(GADRequest())

    }

    func adViewDidReceiveAd(_ bannerView: GADBannerView) {
        banner.isHidden = false
    }

    func adView(_ bannerView: GADBannerView, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: GADRequestError) {

        banner.isHidden = true
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you created an instance of the GADBannerView? Also, have you added the banner to the view?

Comment: Yes. I have added the banner to the view

Comment: Have you instantiated the banner, i'm not sure about IB but programatically it would be something like `banner= GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeBanner)`

Comment: picture 1. https://ibb.co/Phs5mj7. picture 2. https://ibb.co/rGBpbjr

Comment: Oh okay. Have you tried cloning the official banner sample code from here(https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob/BannerExample) and seeing if it builds and runs?

Comment: Yes. I tried a lot

Comment: I think you can click the top left warning button to see more readable errors than the stack trace. Also, does it work with the test ad id?

Comment: Forget that, scroll to the top of the stack trace. What does the message say?

Comment: I try this link https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-ios-examples/tree/master/Swift/admob/BannerExample I don't find file of name GoogleMobileAds.framework

Comment: Drag and drop from your other project and it should work. And please edit the question with the stack trace.

Comment: I try to Drag and drop from my project but not work it
I used this GoogleMobileAdsSdkiOS-7.44.0

Comment: Project -> Build Phases -> Target -> General -> Embed Binaries -> Add Other -> Select Framework -> Copy Items if needed -> Done.

Comment: This app could not be installed at this time.
Failed to load Info.plist from bundle at path /Users/faisal/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/8FC1797F-91B1-4253-B26A-5E1756B82624/data/Library/Caches/com.apple.mobile.installd.staging/temp.2XPQ9k/extracted/Payload/NewTry.app/Frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework

Comment: Click "Simulator" then "Reset Content and Settings..." And  clean and rebuild see if it still persists.

Comment: If it doesn't work, I need to see the stack trace from the build that produced  "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" in order to fix it.

Comment: Still it there is this  problem "This app could not be installed at this time"